# How to enter info from notebook touch pad with Java

Tags: java, touchpad

I wonder if there is any sample Java program that shows how to get info from notebook touch pads, for instance if I want to develop a Java app that can get users' handwriting from the touch pad. It's like drawing with a mouse into a canvas, except I want to use my finger to enter info.

Comment: do you mean the mouse pad on a laptop? or some external device?

Comment: I mean the mouse pad. Thanks for the answers and questions, now I am more clear of what I was looking for, just write a program that keeps track of the mouse/finger movements to get user handwriting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're talking about the mouse pad on a laptop, you could just create a MouseMotionListener that tracks the mouse's location and creates an array of coordinates.

Comment: Great idea, so there's no need for any special pen, just use a finger to draw or write into a Java app.